# Block emails from TLD on Outlook 365 w/o Junk, 3rd party programs, or scripts?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, spam-prevention

Is it possible to block an entire TLD in Outlook 365?

I've been getting a ton of spam emails lately, and I want to set up rules to automatically delete them. I set up a rule to block certain TLDs, but it isn't working, and I'm not sure why.

The rule is set up to mark as read and delete any email with an address that contains ".ng", ".nig", ".com.", ".org.". However, when I have an email that meets those criteria in my inbox and run the rule, nothing happens. I did check the header of the email in question to be sure what I was seeing in the email matched the header. It was obviously a fake email address, but what I entered matched where Outlook thought it was coming from.

I've looked online, but the fixes I've seen either start with "click the gear icon" (I don't have one), "click tools" (ditto), "right click on the email and select Junk" (greyed out since IT updated our email to 365). I cannot add a third-party program as the company doesn't allow that.

Any suggestions or links to instructions that might work for me?

**ETA**: Yes, I have asked IT. Right now they're handling issues/requests from people far above me in the corporate hierarchy. I've passed the two-month mark so far, and I'm still being told they will look at it "as soon as they have time."

Comment: You should talk to your IT people.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about enterprise/corporate technology, and OP has an IT department they should work with to solve their problem.

Comment: I'd love to, and I have asked. Unfortunately, their time is fully occupied by people much higher on the totem pole than I am, who apparently do not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Power of Google compelled me to search on "Outlook email block entire domain" which found [these helpful hints](https://www.ptd.net/help-desk/email-communication/advanced/how-block-email-address-or-entire-domain):

Your original post was tagged "Outlook 2010: so this answer is for folks with Outlook 2010.

In Outlook 2010, pick the "**Junk**" button and choose "**Junk email Options...**".
To add an email address to the *Blocked Senders List* click "**Add...**"
This leads you to a dialog box titled

> Add address or domain
>   Enter an e-mail address or Internet domain name to be added to the list.

Add your problematic domain and click OK.

Thank you, PenTeleData Help Desk!

Now, for Outlook 365...

Pick the Gear Icon (AKA the settings icon) *IF YOU HAVE ONE*.
Click on **Options**.
Under **Preventing junk mail**, Click on **Safe and blocked senders**.
Click on **Blocked senders**.
Add the problematic domain to mark as blocked.
Click on **Add to list**.

Sadly, this really requires IT intervention, for they have blocked your access to Settings.

Comment: IT has, for reasons known only to IT, eliminated our ability to use the 'Junk' button, but thank you!

Comment: I don't have the gear, either. Trust me, I've looked. And for some reason, there is no Outlook-365 tag, and my karma isn't high enough to let me add it.

Comment: Closest tag used 'office365'